# How to execute php script from Javascript Value

Tags: javascript, php

I have a javascript pop-up box that asks the user if they wish to delete the current entry, it has a Yes, No and cancel button.

I want to allow the users to have a choice, if they select Yes, the code will run the php script to delete a column from the database. If no, the pop-up box will dissapear and nothing will happen. Same goes for cancel.

How would I achieve this? Here's my javascript code;

```
<script>
function deletekey() {
new Messi('Are you sure you want to delete your key?', {title: 'Delete?', buttons: [{id: 0, label: 'Yes', val: 'Y', class: 'btn-success'}, {id: 1, label: 'No', val: 'N', class: 'btn-danger'}, {id: 2, label: 'Cancel', val: 'C'}]});
}
</script>
```

Comment: You are using http://marcosesperon.es/apps/messi/ ? In that case add a callback function (as shown in the example "Message ...and callback function." and let this callback make an ajax call so taht the php script is invoked.

Comment: Use Ajax.With AJAX you could connect a client side script(Javascript) to a server side script(PHP) and get them to "talk" to eachother.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, however I am not very experienced with Javascript, how would I do this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: [This](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/) Will Help You To Get Started With AJAX.If You Don't Like To Use AJAX, You're Going To Have To Submit Forms Like The Way People Used To Do Things.